# Repeat VBA Loop in to next row issue

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

So this code works fine if I were to be wanting to bring back the data to cells D3-P3 (If I picked starting merch cat as cell D2, starting site as 0930 and starting cell as D3).
However I can't seem to think of a solution to make it complete this action, then change 'myvalue2' from '0930' (the current selection) to the next cell down '0125' and run the exact same code. This will need to be repeated until the last cell in column 'C' has been covered. Any thoughts?

```
Sub newreplacewithrange()
 
 
 Dim myValue As Range
 Dim myValue2 As Range
 Dim scell As Range
 Dim x As String
 
    
 Set myValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select Cell that first merch cat is in", Type:=8)
 Set myValue2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select Cell that first site is in", Type:=8)
 Set startcell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select starting cell", Type:=8)
 Set rangecheck = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select site cell range", Type:=8)

 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("BA1").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[5]&RC[1]"
    Range("BA1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BA1:BA" & LastRow)

 startcell.Select

 On Error Resume Next
 
 Do
 
 If ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False) = "#N/A" Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                    Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
                    
 Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" and
           ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False) <>"#N/A" then
ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False) 
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                    Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
 Else
    If x = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False) = ActiveCell Then
           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                  Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
 Else
    If x = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False) <> ActiveCell Then
           ActiveCell.ClearNotes
                   ActiveCell.AddCommentThreaded ("Was " & ActiveCell.Value)
                         ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                                       Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
 End If
 End If
 End If
 End If
 
 
 Loop Until IsEmpty(myValue.Value)

 
 
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap it within a for loop?

Comment: Useless comment incoming: That is the most colorful sheet I have ever seen

Comment: Haha, I work with a lot of spreadsheets! Yes I was thinking of using a 'for' loop but not quite sure how to incorporate it to run the code as described in the description. Any advice welcome

Comment: I would just like to point out that in the evaluation of the first `If` the `True` part will never happen, because ActiveCell.value is required with two distinct AND different values.

Comment: Incorrect, it is stating that if the active cell is blank and the vlookup to that cell equals #N/A then move to next cell

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer:

```
 Dim myValue As Range
 Dim myValue2 As Range
 Dim x As String
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim WB As Workbook
 Dim WS1 As Worksheet
 
 Set WB = Workbooks("NSAR")
 Set WS1 = WB.Sheets("TA")
 Set myValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select Cell that first merch cat is in", Type:=8)
 Set myValue2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select Cell that first site is in", Type:=8)
 Set startcell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select starting cell", Type:=8)
 Set siterange = Application.Range(myValue2, myValue2.End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

startcell.Select

'Go to starting cell location
 
 For Each cell In siterange

'For each cell in the site column, run this code that checks if the formula for each concatenation of site number & merch cat number brings back a new value
'If the grade brought back is the same as current then do nothing, if different then bring back the new grade and comment what the old grade was in the same cell
'Go to the next merch cat and repeat
'Go to the next site and repeat process

 On Error Resume Next
 
i = 1
  
 Do
    
 If ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F")) = "#N/A" Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                    Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                    
 Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F")) <> "#N/A" Then
ActiveCell = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F"))
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                        Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
                        i = i + 1
     Else
        If ActiveCell.Value = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F")) = ActiveCell Then
               ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                      Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
                      i = i + 1
     Else
        If ActiveCell.Value = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F")) <> ActiveCell Then
                         cell.ClearNotes
                       ActiveCell.AddCommentThreaded ("Was " & ActiveCell.Value)
                             ActiveCell = Application.XLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], WS1.Range("AX:AX"), WS1.Range("F:F"))
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                                           Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, 1)
                                           i = i + 1
     End If
     End If
     End If
     End If
     
     
    
    
     Loop Until IsEmpty(myValue.Value)
     
     
     Set startcell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -i + 1)
     Set myValue2 = myValue2.Offset(1, 0)
     Set myValue = myValue.Offset(0, -i + 1)
     
'Reset the positioning of the starting cell, the merch cat number and move to the next site

    startcell.Select
     
    
    Next cell
                
 
 'Look at doing this to open refit tab. send lookup in to there

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Comments Updated"
 
 
 End Sub
```